# Drag image from browser to Desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drag-and-drop

I want to drag image from browser to Desktop.

I have for example an image with src is a miniature (small picture) and the name is the big image.

When I drag the image from browser to desktop, the small image will be dragged and not the big image.

So how can I drag the big picture ? How can I do that by jQuery or JS ?

```html
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iUJHpIju24o/UlQA-x8J7qI/AAAAAAAANVI/clUJZjFsm18/s640/plant_1280.jpg" name= "https://live.staticflickr.com/6120/6246147468_e5190345a5_h.jpg" >
```

Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a little tricky code , using `mouseover` and `mouseout`

**On `mouseover`**

- , set original height and wight as style to the image (to preserve thum image hieght witdh ) ,
- then store thmb url in data attribute , and replace `src` of image by the hd url  in `name` attribute

**after `mouseout` (mouse leave the image )** ,

- remove the style attribute (no nedd height and width )
- restore thumb original url to the image `src` attribute

Now if you check drag en drop , it will store the hd image instead of thmbs image ::

See below working snippet :

```js
$("#img").mouseover(function(e) {

  // store thumb url in data attribute in order to get it after mouseout
  $(this).data("url", $(this).attr("src"));
  

  // set height , width of orignal thumb for use experience 
  $(this).css({
    "width": $(this).width(),
    "height": $(this).height()
  })
  
  // change url src to hd image
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("name"));

});

$("#img").mouseout(function(e) {
  // restore original thumb image
  $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("url"));

  // remove style added on hover 
  $(this).removeAttr("style");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iUJHpIju24o/UlQA-x8J7qI/AAAAAAAANVI/clUJZjFsm18/s640/plant_1280.jpg" name="https://live.staticflickr.com/6120/6246147468_e5190345a5_h.jpg">
```

Comment: This is great and answers the question perfectly and works nicely - but it begs the question (for OP): why bother with the mouseout, just leave the larger image in the page.

Comment: @freedomn-m , you're right , I should let the original , but I dont know if it could make some performance in case of multiples images in window , I have to check first , 
thanks for the remark

Comment: Ah yes, could have performance implications if there are a lot of very large images left in the page.

Comment: miss @SoumayaMORABIT , is it usefull , or you've other issues ?

Comment: it works perfectly, thank you very much, but I have another question please : how can I drag at once more than one picture for example ?